# Keeping a bitmap in memory with the help of onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

I have a large bitmap that i would like to keep in memory when the qwerty keyboard is visible. My app is always in landscape, so this is the only configuration change that will cause a reDraw. I heard this is what onRetainNonConfigurationinstance() is for...but cant figure it out. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
    @Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return bitMap;
}
```

in onCreate call getLastNonConfigurationInstance(); to recive the bitmap

I hade a smilare read about it [Save cache when rotate device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250987/save-cache-when-rotate-device/3252547#3252547)