# handling device rotation with camera activity

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin.android

I have an activity which the first thing it does is send a camera intent. I want the user to take a picture and then I will use it to do something. My problem is that If the user changes the rotation while taking the picture the app keeps on looping inside the camera until he finishes the entire process while staying in a single device orientation.

Here is the code:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        _dateTextView = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.DateLabel);
        ViewModel.RecomendDishViewModel.RecomendationSent += RecomendationSent;
        if (IsThereAnAppToTakePictures())
        {
            CreateDirectoryForPictures();
            var imageButton = FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.TakeImageWaterMark);
            _imageView = FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.UserDishImage);
            imageButton.Click += TakePictureClicked;
            if(_bitmap != null)
            {
                _imageView.RecycleBitmap ();
                _imageView.SetImageBitmap(_bitmap);
            }
        }
        _dateTextView.Click += DateLabelClicked;
        TakePictureClicked ()
    }
protected void TakePictureClicked ()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
        _file = new Java.IO.File(_dir, String.Format("myPhoto_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));
        intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Uri.FromFile(_file));
        StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // make it available in the gallery
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.FromFile(_file);
        mediaScanIntent.SetData(contentUri);
        SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

        // display in ImageView. We will resize the bitmap to fit the display
        // Loading the full sized image will consume to much memory 
        // and cause the application to crash.
        _bitmap = _file.Path.LoadAndResizeBitmap (518, 388);
        if(_bitmap != null)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            _bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
            byte[] bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
            ViewModel.RecomendDishViewModel.ImageData = bitmapData;
            if(_imageView == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            _imageView.RecycleBitmap ();
            _imageView.SetImageBitmap(_bitmap);
        }
        _file.Dispose ();
        _dir.Dispose ();
    }
```

My problem is that the activity gets recreated and then launches the camera app again. I have tried many things (this is the clean version) but nothing worked perfectly...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly the solution you were looking for, but you could try simply locking screen rotation during the activity.

You can set this in the Android Manifest like so:

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity" 
android:screenOrientation="portrait">
...
</activity>
```

This will keep the activity from redrawing when the device is rotated. Obviously you can replace "portrait" with "landscape" if you feel that a landscape layout would be more appropriate for your activity.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend saving the state of the Activity like a Question before that I gave advice on.

Sadly, I'd failed. : )

[Save State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174266/prevent-activity-from-reload-after-rotation-in-xamarin-monodroid/18174918#18174918)

Answer (score 0):

To add to Slack Shots answer your really need to understand what is going on within the activity life cycle you either need to lock the orientation of your app and prevent changes or  the better way (save state) or handle the orientation changes directly.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html